# Why Postgres on GCP is not using all the available memory?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I have a Postgres instance on GCP with incredibly slow queries. The database structure is very bad, but I believe something else is also affecting performance.

Although the instance has 4GB of memory available, it never even reaches 1GB of usage.

I've been playing around with Postgres configuration, but nothing seems to change the performance or the memory usage.

I assume that if the queries are really bad, they'd use a lot of memory and CPU, but I have queries running for 11 seconds and still only 1GB of memory.

Where should I be looking besides the mem config on Postgres?

My current settings are

[image]

And here is the memory chart

[image]

Comment: Look at `explain (analyze, buffers)` for a slow query.

Comment: All your memory is used for the database. Google probably just doesn't show it.

Comment: How large are the individual databases?

Comment: Not even a GiB, 250mb.

Answer (score 0):

[Query insights](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-query-insights#enable-insights) provide some guidelines to assist you on your database to prevent query performance problems for Cloud SQL databases.

You should look into [IO Wait and Lock Wait](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/using-query-insights#using-db-load-graph) when these two are in spike during the execution of your query. you should check your queries for tables that hold the lock unecessarily. To check on which table is holding the lock you can check [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html).

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks;
```

Note: PostgreSQL are known to access data tables concurrently. If there is a table that have the lock it will disable the `concurrent` method of PostgreSQL. Resulting in longer query execution time.

To know more about [PostgresSQl concurrent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html)